# WCF Dynamic Binding - How to specify end points?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to bind my WCF client using code instead of app.config as I'll need to change host IP addresses for different deployment.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICX" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" >
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1/CX/CX.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICX" contract="CXService.ICX" name="WSHttpBinding_ICX">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="host/SilverStar" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and this is my code:

```
public static void StartUp()
{
    XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quota = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
    quota.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
    quota.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
    quota.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
    quota.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
    quota.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
    EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/CX/CX.svc"));

    WSHttpBinding binding1 = new WSHttpBinding();
    binding1.Name = "WSHttpBinding_ICX";
    binding1.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1073741824;
    binding1.ReaderQuotas = quota;

    // Globals.CXClient is the client object
    Globals.CXClient = new CXService.CXClient(binding1, addr);

    // This line does not compile! Endpoint is read-only!!
    Globals.CXClient.Endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("CXService.ICX"), (Binding)binding1, addr);
}
```

The last line of the code does not compile as .EndPoint is read-only property.

Please help.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx) website.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Globals.CXClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("your url here");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
Globals.CXClient.Endpoint.Contract = new ContractDescription("CXService.ICX");
Globals.CXClient.Endpoint.Binding = binding1;
Globals.CXClient.Endpoint.Address = addr;
```

However, I encountered another problem. I tried to replace the part:

```
<identity>
    <servicePrincipalName value="host/SilverStar" />
</identity>
```

by using the following code:

```
addr.Identity = new SpnEndpointIdentity("host/SilverStar");
```

This one again fails to compile because addr.Identity is read-only.

I also tried this:

```
EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/CX/CX.svc"), new SpnEndpointIdentity("host/SilverStar"), ???);
```

but the last parameter is an AddressHeaderCollection and I have no idea what should be placed in there.

Please help again. Thanks.